# Is there a way to cache Audio file in flutter app From Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, streaming

**Hello World** 
I am building an audio streaming app using **flutter** and I have all the audio files on firebase storage.

I want to implement the Youtube or Audiomack save offline. in this case, the offline downloaded media file is encrypted so that it can't be found in the device file part.

please I need help from anyone.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this package [flutter_cache_manager_firebase](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager_firebase)  which is  an implementation for [flutter_cache_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager)

This library contains FirebaseCacheManager and FirebaseHttpFileService.

You can easily fetch a file stored on Firebase with

```
var file = await FirebaseCacheManager().getSingleFile(url);
```

you can always create a custom FirebaseHttpFileService

to cache the data flutter cache manager

```
CustomCacheManager._() : super(key,
      maxAgeCacheObject: Duration(days: 7),
      maxNrOfCacheObjects: 20);
```

Comment: I Want the audio file to be persistent so that the cache doesn't clear for like 3 months